# If condition is not working in my case using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

**Test Plan**

1. Sending post requests for login with required parameters
2. In response of above I am getting 1 GET request

I am storing above GET requests in variable using `BeanShell PostProcessor` like :

```
String URL = prev.getURL().toString();
log.info(URL);
```

3. Now I am trying to put IF condition based on above **URL** variable value.

i.e

```
if("${URL}"=="https://www.example.com")
              //do something
```

But above IF condition not working. Even If put correct value as expected and actual , during script run seems conditions skips or being false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it inside Beanshell script consider using [vars.get("URL")](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get(java.lang.String)) instead of accessing the variable like `${URL}`.

Going forward kindly avoid inlining variables and functions into Beanshell scripts as they may resolve into something causing at least syntax error.

Also don't compare strings using `==` operator, use [String.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method instead.

Correct code will looks like:

```
String URL = prev.getURL().toString();
log.info(URL);
vars.put("URL", URL); // store URL value into a JMeter Variable

if (vars.get("URL").equals("https://www.example.com")) {
    //do what you need here
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on Beanshell scripting in Jmeter.